# Keeping a custom theme up to date with upstream

Tags: wordpress, git, version-control, wordpress-theming

My team will be working on a Wordpress project (theme), and we're looking to build using the Foundation CSS framework. Additionally, we will be making use of Git as source control.

We've discovered the Foundationpress theme, and would like to use it as a starting point: https://github.com/olefredrik/FoundationPress

We would only want to do this once in a while, ie maybe there is a bug in the current version that gets fixed.

My question is, how can we keep up to date with changes to the Foundationpress theme selectively?

ie: Should I fork the project, and change the remote origin to our Github repository, and add a secondary remote for the Foundationpress repo, and then only pull down changes from the Foundationpress remote when needed? I'm just not really sure what the best practice is.

Maybe there's a better way to handle this entirely. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you fork the `olefredrik/FoundationPress`, your fork repo will not contain the update changes that `olefredrik/FoundationPress` made.

If you don’t need to contribute for `olefredrik/FoundationPress`, and you already have your own remote repo you want to work on, you can directly add remote by `git remote add upstream https://github.com/olefredrik/FoundationPress.git`, and check if there has update by

```
git fetch upstream
git log master..upstream/master
```

If there has output, that means `olefredrik/FoundationPress` has new commit(s) which is(are) not contains in your local repo. You can use `git pull upstream master` to pull the new changes.

If you need to contribute for `olefredrik/FoundationPress` or you don’t have your own remote repo, so you can fork it and check if there has update changes by the same way above.